# Changing RichHtmlField's DefaultAssetImageLocation property

Tags: 2013, page-layout

I am attempting to set the default location when selecting Insert->Picture->From SharePoint in my `RichHtmlField`. I have set the `DefaultAssetImageLocation` on my page layout's `RichHtmlField` and while it appears to be carrying over the correct URL, it seems to be overriden by another parameter `DefaultToLastUsedLocation` which is forcing it to open the asset image dialog in the last used location.

`DefaultToLastUsedLocation` doesn't appear to be a part of the `RichHtmlField` object. Is it possible to remove this or modify it to avoid this behavior?

Looking at the JS that executes on the page, there are a couple of things going wrong it seems that are causing issues.

1) The `DefaultToLastUsedLocation` doesn't seem to be accessible through the `RichHtmlField` control.

2) You can override `DefaultToLastUsedLocation` using the `AssetPickerConfig` variable.

3) It appears that the `ImageAsset` constructor called on the page does not provide an `AssetUrl` parameter, it just passes in an empty string.

4) `AssetUrl` seems to completely override `DefaultAssetLocation` and `DefaultAssetImageLocation`, as setting the `AssetUrl` appears to be the only way to direct to a specific Url.

5) I have not found a way to set the `AssetUrl` property except by overriding the function call that tries to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using SPUrl to build your relative URL?

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichImageField
    FieldName="PublishingRollupImage" 
    runat="server" 
    DefaultAssetImageLocation="<% $SPUrl:~site/Lists/SiteAssets/ %>"
/>
```

Comment: Yes, it does not help.

Comment: This would also not help with step 1, where the property DefaultToLastUsedLocation is not accessible from RichHtmlField. Unless I'm misunderstanding your use of RichImageField.

Comment: DefaultToLastUsedLocation  is not a property member of RichHtmlField.           https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.richhtmlfield_properties

Comment: @DipenShah That's correct, so part of the solution must involve a way to manipulate that property when using a RichHtmlField which exposes an Image Asset Picker.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that I'm a bit late to the party, but I figured out something that helped me greatly with the same problem mentioned above.

I used the same snippet, but discovered that it did not render from HTML to aspx properly.

`<PublishingWebControls:RichImageField
    FieldName="PublishingRollupImage" 
    runat="server" 
    DefaultAssetImageLocation="<% $SPUrl:~site/Lists/SiteAssets/ %>"`

To fix this, I did two things:

1. Apply a 'char encode tag' to the additional PageHead:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

source and explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24062268

1. Encode the angle brackets around the value for DefaultImageAssetLocation like this:

`&lt;% $SPUrl:~site/PublishingImages / %&gt;`

The entire snippet in my HTML page layout file looks like this (note: I'm using a RichImageField):

`<!--MS:<PageFieldRichImageField:RichImageField DefaultAssetImageLocation="&lt;% $SPUrl:~site/PublishingImages / %&gt;" FieldName="3de94b06-4120-41a5-b907-88773e493458" runat="server">-->`

Now everytime I browse for an image, my preferred location is shown by default!

I hope this helps anyone.

Comment: This would not help with step 1, where the property DefaultToLastUsedLocation is not accessible from RichHtmlField. RichHtmlField allows the user to insert an image through the ribbon's Insert section. This is the image asset picker used in RichImageFIeld iirc, but when there is no declaration for a RichImageFIeld when declaring a RichHtmlField